# Save addition information in payment method on Order Page

Tags: magento-1.8

I have created custom payment module in Magento for emi options.

But the issue is that when person place order, then in the invoice I can only see the payment method they used for place order, But cannot see emi option they have selected.

For example: this time it is showing me

```
Payment method:
xyz payment
```

But I also want add addition selected option like that:

```
Payment method
xyz payment
3 month emi
```

So, Please guide how can I use this in my payment module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In payment, to show extra information you will use the `info` block.

> Step1:

Assign the info block in your custom payment model file

```
protected $_infoBlockType = 'payment/info_[custom_payment_name]';
```

> Step 2:

Need to set emi options in `$this->getInfoInstance()`. Please refer the `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Purchaseorder` file and function name `assignData()`

```
$this->getInfoInstance()->setAdditionalData([get emi option value]);
```

for ex:

```
$details['emi'] = 'xxxx';
$this->getInfoInstance()->setAdditionalData(serialize($details));
```

> Step 3:

In Block folder create the payment info file extends info block, assign the payment info template file. Please refer default payment file(Purchaseorder), function name `_construct()` and add the additional data conversion refer below

```
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setTemplate('payment/info/[custompayment].phtml');
}

protected $_emi;

public function getEmi()
{
     if (is_null($this->_emi)) {
        $this->_convertAdditionalData();
     }
     return $this->_emi;
}

protected function _convertAdditionalData()
{
    $this->_emi = '';

    $details = @unserialize($this->getInfo()->getAdditionalData());        
    if (is_array($details)) {
         $this->_emi = isset($details['emi']) ? (string) $details['emi'] : '';
    }
    return $this;
}
```

> Step 4:

Create phtml file design folder under current theme, `app/design/fronted/[package]/[theme]/template/payment/info/[custom_payment_name].phtml`

```
<?php  
echo ( if($this->getEmi()) ? $this->getEmi() : '');  
?>
```

Please check `additional_data` field in `sales_flat_order_payment` table for that last order, you can find the data details added.

Try this. Hope this help you

Comment: I have created Block/Info/Pay.php file, And created Class 
   Class Namespace_Module_Block_Info_Pay {
    }
So Please tell me if it is need to extend this class, then with which class I can extend this new which I have created

Comment: You have to extend `Mage_Payment_Block_Info` class and assign the template file in constructor, you going to create in design template file. (Refer purchaseorder.php you will get idea)

Comment: If you used `payment/info_pay` then you have to create `Pay.php` file in Block folder, assign template file in constructor and create `pay.phtml` in current theme template folder, so your file path as app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/payment/info/pay.phtml

Comment: I did exactly as you mentioned. But it is returning nothing.. Blank

Comment: Could you please share the code

Comment: sure, How can I highlighting code in comment as you are highlighting

Comment: Namespace/Module/Model/Standard.php
class Namespace_Module_Model_Standard extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract {

protected $_infoBlockType = 'ebsemi/info_pay';

    public function assignData($data)
    {
        if (!($data instanceof Varien_Object)) {
            $data = new Varien_Object($data);
        }
 $this->getInfoInstance()->setEmi($data->getEmi());
 return $this;
    }
}

Comment: Namespace/Module/Block/Info/Pay.php
class Namespace_Module_Block_Info_Pay extends Mage_Payment_Block_Info{

 protected function _construct()
 {
      parent::_construct();
  $this->setTemplate('payment/info/pay.phtml');
 }
}

Comment: app/design/fronted/[package]/[theme]/template/payment/info/pay.phtml
<?php  
echo ( if($this->getInfo()->getEmi()) ? ($this->getInfo()->getEmi()) : '');  
?>

Comment: Add the code lastly after the question, dont share the code in comments. In editor, have code highlighting formats use that.

Comment: Okay @Venkat, I added new code. Please check it

Answer (score 0):

@venkat, I have used this code in module

> Namespace/Module/Model/Standard.php

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Standard extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract {

    protected $_infoBlockType = 'ebsemi/info_pay';

        public function assignData($data)
        {
            if (!($data instanceof Varien_Object)) {
                $data = new Varien_Object($data);
            }
        $this->getInfoInstance()->setEmi($data->getEmi());
        return $this;
        }
    }
```

> Namespace/Module/Block/Info/Pay.php

```
class Namespace_Module_Block_Info_Pay extends Mage_Payment_Block_Info{

    protected function _construct()
    {
            parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('payment/info/pay.phtml');
    }
}
```

> app/design/fronted/[package]/[theme]/template/payment/info/pay.phtml

```
<?php  
echo ( if($this->getInfo()->getEmi()) ? ($this->getInfo()->getEmi()) : '');  
?>
```

Comment: I figure out issues in the above code. Please refer [this link](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/28/magento-create-custom-payment-method) and update the latest code once you modified.

Comment: My code is as written as guided in this link you have shared. But still returning nothing..

Comment: Please refer my code edited, additional data added in that. Please check and let me know

Comment: @Venkat, That worked thanks buddy. It not saved to database, So it could be added to invoice

Comment: You checked `additional_data` in `sales_flat_order_payment` table for that last order id ?. Surely it have the data in the table.

Comment: @Venkat  Thanks buddy, you are awesome. You solved my problem. Thanks a lot